# Sorting array using binarySearch

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I just want to ask if why am I still getting null pointer on my function `sortInOrder(Object x)`.

What I am trying to do is use `sortInOrder` to insert Objects in my `data[]` array in ascending order.

```
public Object[] data = new Object[10];

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int r = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        System.out.println("Adding " + r);
        sortInOrder(r);

        for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++)
            System.out.println((Integer) data[j]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        System.out.println((Integer) data[i]);
}

public static void sortInOrder(Object x) {
    if (x == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    int idx = 0;
    if ( data[idx] != null ) 
        idx = Arrays.binarySearch(data, 0, data.length-1, ((Integer) data[idx]).compareTo((Integer) x));

    for ( int i = idx + 1 ; i < data.length - 1 ; i++ )
        data[i] = data[ i - 1 ];

    data[idx] = x;
}
```

Comment: `data[i+1]` goes beyond bounds of array when i = data.length-1

Comment: The technique doesn't make sense. Binary search only works on arrays that are already sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed your code. Please note that the return value of binarySearch method is:

"index of the search key, if it is contained in the array within the specified range; otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1)" ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html))

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Q1 {

    public static Object[] data = new Object[10];

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            int r = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
            System.out.print("Adding: " + r);
            sortInOrder(r);

            System.out.print("[");
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                System.out.print(" " + data[j]);
            System.out.println(" ]");
        }

        System.out.print("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            System.out.print(" " + data[i]);
        System.out.print(" ]");
    }

    public static void sortInOrder(Integer x) {
        if (x == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(data, 0, data.length - 1, x, Comparator.nullsLast((Object o1, Object o2) -> ((Integer) o1) - ((Integer) o2)));

        if (idx < 0) idx = -idx - 1;
        System.out.println(" at index: " + idx);

        // Hint: Use arraycopy instead of for loop for better performance
        System.arraycopy(data, idx, data, idx + 1, data.length - 1 - idx);

        data[idx] = x;
    }

}
```

Alternatively You can use an anonymous class instead of lambda:

```
int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(data, 0, data.length - 1, x, 
    Comparator.nullsLast(new Comparator<Object>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return ((Integer) o1) - ((Integer) o2);
        }
    }));
```

Result:

```
Adding: 2 at index: 0
[ 2 null null null null null null null null null ]
Adding: 29 at index: 1
[ 2 29 null null null null null null null null ]
Adding: 88 at index: 2
[ 2 29 88 null null null null null null null ]
Adding: 9 at index: 1
[ 2 9 29 88 null null null null null null ]
Adding: 27 at index: 2
[ 2 9 27 29 88 null null null null null ]
[ 2 9 27 29 88 null null null null null ]
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I have a problem with this. It doesn't work if it's sortInOrder(Object x). Should use (Integer x) to make it work. Any idea why? I tried to cast but don't know where.

Comment: The program should work even if it's not an Integer like Strings for example. Thanks

Comment: What kinds of objects will be stored in the array? You have to define the order in some way, so You have to make some assumptions on what will be stored there and then You can define a custom comparator.

Comment: Well basically more like numbers. But we want to use generics instead of just Integers.

Comment: Ok, so what `sortInOrder` should do, when it is called with an `Integer` `42`, then with `String` `"one"` and then with `Integer` `5`? How You'd like to define an order there? There are many possible solutions for that...

Comment: Let's just stick with Integers. But it should be Object or generic type T.

Comment: So what does this actually do? I don't get it. I tried googling it and it's hard to understand what it does. Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder())

Comment: Basically `Comparator`s define an order for some class of elements. They have to implement a function that takes two elements `a` and `b` and returns a signed integer. If `a` and `b` should be considered equal, the result should be 0.

Comment: Java has already defined a `naturalOrder` comparator, which I've used in my previous solution: `Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder()`. That comparator defines standard ascending order of Integers. It's method `compare` could be implemented like this: `(Integer a, Integer b) -> a - b`.

Comment: And the nullsLast just basically ignore nulls? Am i right?

Comment: The comparator `Comparator.nullsLast(cmp)` is parametrized by another Comparator. It basically extends the order to `null` values, so that they're considered greater than any other value of given kind. In case when both parameters of its `compare` method are not `null`, it simply uses its argument `cmp` to compare them.

Comment: Small example: If we have an array like that: `Integer[] ints = { 3,5, null, 1,7, null };`, then when it is sorted with `Arrays.sort(ints, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder()));`, the result is `[null, null, 1, 3, 5, 7]`, and when we use `Arrays.sort(ints, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder()));` instead, the result will be: `[1, 3, 5, 7, null, null]`.